# Plupload upload file missing xsrf argument in tornado xsrf mode?

Tags: csrf, tornado, plupload

```
WARNING:root:403 POST /upload (127.0.0.1): '_xsrf' argument missing from POST  
WARNING:root:403 POST /upload (127.0.0.1) 2.95ms
```

What did I deal with?

Comment: do you solve it? I have this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

The server to which you are attempting to upload a file does not allow uploads without the appropriate XSRF value. This value is supplied by per-user cookie.

Apart from having the appropriate cookie, you must ensure that your upload form contains a field for this value.  Tornado provides a `xsrf_form_html()` function which you'd call from your form, e.g.:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post">
  {{ xsrf_form_html() }}
  <input type="text" name="foo"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

References:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery
http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html?highlight=forgery#cross-site-request-forgery-protection

Comment: A little note here: If you have auto-escape enabled this function doesn't work properly because in an escaped form it has no impact on the `<form>`. To make it work in every case use `{% raw xsrf_form_html() %}`